# Regular expression to require 10 digits without considering spaces

Tags: regex, salesforce, crm

I need a regex to limit number digits to 10 even if there are spaces.

For example it allows `06 15 20 47 23` the same as `0615204723`.

I tried: `^\d{10}$`, but how do I ignore spaces?

Also, the number should start with `06` or `07`.  (Editor's note, the last requirement was from comments by the OP.)

Comment: How will you use this regex? In perl, this would be very simple.

Answer (score 7):

This will do it in most regex systems. (You need to state what language you are using!)

```
/^\s*(0\s*[67]\s*(?:\d\s*){8})$/
```

But assuming you really only want the number, then go ahead and break it into 2 steps.

For example, in JavaScript:

```
var s = ' 06 15 20 47   34 ';
s = s.replace (/\s/g, "");
isValid = /^0[67]\d{8}$/.test (s);
```

Comment: Hello , I am not using any languyage .Am iam working on Salesforce (Cloud cmputing CRM ) and i only need to write a regex expression. I tried yours it allows spaces after writing 06 , for example 06 15 20 47 41 , but it doesn't allow space between 0 and 6 .You see?

Comment: Updated the answer to allow for spaces between the 0 and the 6.  And yes, you are using a language.  The question should state that the regex is for Salesforce CRM.  Several of us will then know that Java syntax is most-likely allowed.

Comment: this was the best answer for me, useful to note that the quantifier: {8} is 8 and not ten because of the requirement for the start to begin with either 06 or 07 which takes up two digits. My requirement was that number must be 11 digits only, so added {11} but as soon as I needed it to begin with 0 the regex obviously broke.. changing it to {10} thus fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
"^(\d *){10}$"
```

Comment: Thanks for you all for your answers , i tried this and it works to avoid spaces , but when i add condition so that number should start with 06 or 07 it doesn't work , it is like ^(0[6-7][0-9] *){8}$   , is it correct? ( Sorry i am new at regex)

Comment: Thanks , but this doesnt ignore spaces

Answer (score 2):

Slightly preferable:

```
"^\s*(\d\s*){10}$"
```

Where \s is any whitespace and \d is a digit. This allows for leading as well as infixed and trailing any group of spaces.

Comment: don't you want `\s*` for zero-or-more whitespace, rather than `\s?` which means zero-or-one?

Comment: Please i need that number to be 10 digits but starting by 06 or 07 , and ignoring spaces as well , i did this ^(0[6-7][0-9] *){10}$, but it doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I noticed if I grouped each digit with any number of spaces padding the front and back, I got the solution I was looking for.  In this example, ignores all spaces

```
^(\s*\d\s*){10}$

eg. "1234567890"
    " 12  34 567   89 0    "
```

In a more complicated example, this ignored all spaces, dashes, round braces and spaces.

```
^([\s\(\)\-]*\d[\s\(\)\-]*){10}$

eg. "(123)456-7890"
    "   (   12 (3)( - 45 - 6-78 )(90 (((--  "
```

Test them out here, it will provide you with the code for your given system:
http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

```
(\s*\d\s*){0,10}
```

This should allow leading and trailing spaces around digits, and match 0 to 10 digits.

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = " a b c d e f g "; 
var newStr = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question (this answer was in the Low Quality Posts review queue).