# HTML input accept only numbers and email

Tags: javascript, html

How can I set html input to accept only numbers and email Id?

```
<input id="input" type="text" />
```

Comment: Html5 offers a variety of preset input types I.e. dates but no mixed types. You'll need some JS in the validation process of the form before submit.

Comment: Yah I know, I searched on the web but I didn't find any solutions for using JS

Comment: It's pretty easy to create the code you need but I'll need the phone call structure (I.e. xxx-xxx-xxxx) to give you a fitting example.

Comment: limit the numbers by 8 digits, no structure required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above in the comments, this should work if you want to accept both 8-digit phone numbers and email addresses:

HTML form code:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateInput()">
  <input type="text" name"mail_or_phone"/>
</form>
```

JS validation:

```
function validateInput()
{
  var fieldValue= document.getElementById("mail_or_phone").value;

  // taken from this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126345/regular-expression-to-require-10-digits-without-considering-spaces      
  var phoneValidation= /^([\s\(\)\-]*\d[\s\(\)\-]*){8}$/; 
  var mailValidation= /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  if (fieldValue.match(phoneValidation)) {
    // correct phone structure
    return true;
  } else if (fieldValue.match(mailValidation)) {
    // correct mail format
    return true;
  } else {
    // incorrect structure
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fanbgqx/) showing an example of the above code. In case of an incorrect answer you should show some kind of warning (not included in the code).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="input" type="number" />
<input id="input" type="email" />
```

Check [this info](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) out on w3schools

... I see you want the same input, so you would stick with text then check the input using regex

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b.
```

then whatever regex you need to validate your number

Answer (score 0):

You can set input to `type="email"` and `type="tel"`.

Comment: I want in same input field not two different input fields

Comment: I see, then you'll have to write validation in javascript. Try a regular expression. You might have to write a regular expression to your liking regexr is good for that. Then override the onsubmit function and make sure your info only gets submitted if it matches the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a simple regex against the phone number and the email. That will most likely not catch all issues but it will give you a starting point.

Pseudo code:

```
//if input is phone
  // do something
// else if input is email
  // do something else
// else (when it is neither)
  // throw an error
```

or you can even shorten this

```
// if input is phone or input is email 
  // do something
//else
  //trow error
```

You can find a ton of regex solutions in the library at regex101.com. There is a whole bunch of email and phone number validators.

One that is supposed to check both (and I didn't look to deeply into the regex) is: `\(^\+[0-9]{9,15}$)|(^.+@.+\..+$)\i`

This should be true if the input string is a phone or email. However, like I said above, it most likely needs refinement.